# How does new species come into existence?

Tags: genetics, gene, speciation

The only reason for the creation of new species that I found from the internet is geographical isolation. Are there any more reasons?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For this question, you can easily find good answers [online](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01) and as such this question seems to fit this sites criteria for ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). ——— Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A paper from Müller et al. proposes a molecular marker called a CBC, differences in which can be used to call two different species, even when closely related: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1950759/

> In this study we are looking for a molecular classifier that might indicate that two organisms belong to different species. We are interested in an indicator hypothesis that is easy to work upon and additionally yields a certain probability that two organisms belong to distinct species. Compensatory base changes (CBCs) in the internal transcribed spacer 2 region (ITS2) of the nuclear rRNA cistron have been suggested as such a classifier.

Some mutation event that creates sufficiently different CBCs in a viable offspring capable of further reproduction, i.e., survives natural selection, would therefore lead to speciation, by this measure.

Comment: So, natural selection is another type of speciation. I understand.

Comment: Natural selection acts on organisms. Some organisms have deleterious mutations. Some have neutral mutations. Some have (more rarely) beneficial mutations. If mutants survive or thrive and (most importantly) reproduce, and if they carry sufficient and specific genetic changes, then those mutants could lead to what this method would term a new species.

Comment: This seems like a very specific answer to a very general question... I see it's been accepted but I'm worried that it's a bit misleading.

Comment: If it is misleading, you're welcome to provide another answer.

Comment: Drive-by downvoting is of no help to improving Stack Exchange, nor this subsite, generally. Clean up your act.